# Trying to print everything after a certain word(string), from a user's answer

Tags: java, substring, indexof

Writing a simple Eliza program for class, and I am stuck.

If the user says

`"I feel"`,

the program needs to ask

`"Why do you feel " +(everything after "I feel") + "?"`.

Right now it is just printing everything I say because the index `idx` is not saving the length of `"I feel"`.

However, the teacher does not want us to put a specific numbers for the substring.

Here is what I have:

```
}else if(userAnswer.toLowerCase().contains("i feel")){
  int idx = userAnswer.indexOf("i feel");
  ElizaAnswer = "Why do you feel " + userAnswer.substring(idx , userAnswer.length()) + "?";
}
```

Comment: The `idx` is the start. You need to add 6 to that; because "i feel" is 6 letters long.

Comment: Why even use a substring? Just put useranswer without calling substring on it

Comment: Sorry, my code probably just sucks. Here was the original.                            (     }else if (userAnswer.substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("I am")) {
  
/*  "I am" fails if the user answer is not at least 4 characters - fix */
  
        ElizaAnswer = "Why are you " + userAnswer.substring(5) + "?";
     }  // end I am

Comment: I was trying to do it without using a specific number, but I don't know what I'm doing. lol

Comment: `idx` is not supposed to save the length of the search expression. It indicates the start of that expression. You have to add the length of the expression to the index to find the end of the expression.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the length of the string "i feel" ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, seriously this is the best website. I will have to use it more often. I realized she was just trying to make me add an && statement to check if the userAnswer is AT LEAST 4 characters, or 6 regarding the "i feel". I was just overthinking this, but thanks for clearing up idx part. I won't do that again. lol derpppppppppp

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the substring (idx in your case) should be the index of where you are starting. So it should be `idx.length()`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that parses a string for a pattern. The function will return the rest of the input.

It's easy to implement if you devide a problem into parts that doing a single thing instead of messing a code with the *hardcoded* data.